# multiple has_many / belongs_to between the same 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm curious how this works... I have several has_many relationships between the same two models.  This is for a calendaring app, so a User can be invited to an Event, a User can attend an Event, and an Event belongs to a User for purposes of seeing who created the event.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :events, through: :invites

  has_many :events

  has_many :attendances, -> { where cancel: false },
                         dependent: :destroy                     
  has_many :events, -> { where "attendances.cancel" => false },
                    through: :attendances
```

**event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :invites

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :attendances, -> { where cancel: false },
                         dependent: :destroy              
  has_many :users, -> { where "attendances.cancel" => false },
                   through: :attendances
```

I also have the corresponding join tables, controlled in their respective models, `attendance.rb`, and `invite.rb`.

So... this works as expected.  A User has Events when they're attending the Event.  I did some tweaking, and realized it was the last thing in the list that was checked.  So, if I move the invites to the bottom, then that's what's checked when I do something like `User.find(1).events`.

Is there a better way to go about this?  I feel like this is just asking for trouble, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I've done this before, I've just changed the name of the relationship to something more unique, then told the `has_many` what class to look at via `class_name`.  You'll likely have to add the `foreign_key` parameter on these changed relationships as well, so the SQL knows which key to match against.

Here's the basic idea:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :invited_events, through: :invites, source: "Event"

  has_many :events # these are events "owned" by the user

  has_many :attendances, -> { where cancel: false }, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :attended_events, -> { where "attendances.cancel" => false }, through: :attendances, source: "Event"
end
```

event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :invitees, through: :invites, source: "User"

  belongs_to :user # this is the owner of the event

  has_many :attendances, -> { where cancel: false }, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :attendees, -> { where "attendances.cancel" => false }, through: :attendances, source: "User"
end
```

Comment: I'm using rails4... it yelled at me about some stuff, and recommended `source:`.  I replaced `class_name: 'Event'` with `source: :event` and all is well.  Does that sound right?